# Issue with Euro character when I create a pdf with redmine's invoices plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, redmine-plugins, invoices

I installed the crm-invoices plugin for redmine.
I selected my currency : euro and I created my first invoice.
But then I select the pdf export option and the euro character is not displayed correctly on the pdf (just a square)
It seems to be utf-8 and prawn related.